# SPARK Sum values and count distinct values Java

Tags: java, apache-spark

My dataset is like this:

```
a,b,c,d
---------
1,2005,A,2
1,2005,A,3
1,2005,B,4
2,2005,A,4
```

The output should be grouped by fields `a`,`b` and then sum `d` values and count distinct `c` values. So the output should be:

```
1,2005,2,9
2,2005,1,4
```

**EDIT**

My code is like :

```
    JavaRDD<String> csv = spark.read().texfile("path.csv").javaRDD();
    JavaRDD<String[]> rdd = csv.map(s -> s.split(","))   
    JavaPairRDD<String , Tuple2<Long, String>> tuple = rdd.mapToPair(x -> new Tuple2<>(x[0]+","+ x[1], new Tuple2<>(x[2], x[3])));
    JavaPairRDD<String , Tuple2<Long, String>> tuple2 = tuple.reduceByKey((x,y) -> x._2()+y._2());
```

But I don't know how to count distinct `c` values.

Comment: can you use Dataframes for this ?

Comment: @QuickSilver no Dataframe, just standard Spark operations.

Comment: can you show me what have you tried can assume what could be the value in the key of JavaPairRdd

Comment: @QuickSilver I edited the question, than you!

Comment: which version of spark you are using?

Comment: the version is 3.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below problem loads a CSV similar to the input you have provided

```
a,b,c,d
1,2005,A,2
1,2005,A,3
1,2005,B,4
2,2005,A,4
```

and does the required mapping and reduce operations,

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import scala.Tuple2;
import scala.Tuple4;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class SimpleDataframe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = Constant.getSparkSess();


        JavaRDD<Row> rdd = spark.read().option("header", "true").csv("src/main/resources/simple.csv").rdd().toJavaRDD();

        List<Tuple4<String, String, Integer, Integer>> output =
                rdd.mapToPair(   // Map input to key(String,String) and value (Collection,Num)
                (PairFunction<Row, Tuple2<String, String>, Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer>>) row -> {
                    Tuple2<String, String> tup1 = new Tuple2<>(row.getString(0), row.getString(1));
                    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
                    set.add(row.getString(2));
                    Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer> tup2 = new Tuple2<>(set, Integer.parseInt(row.getString(3)));
                    return new Tuple2<>(tup1, tup2);
                }
        ).reduceByKey((Function2<Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer>,   // Combine out by key to single tuple per unique tuple1
                        Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer>, Tuple2<Set<String>, Integer>>) (v1, v2) -> {
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
            set.addAll(v1._1);
            set.addAll(v2._1);
            int num = v1._2 + v2._2;
            return new Tuple2<>(set, num);
        }) //// Simplest operation Mapping the combined result to required output
                        .map(tuple -> new Tuple4<>(tuple._1._1, tuple._1._2, tuple._2._1.size(), tuple._2._2))
                .collect();

        System.out.println(output);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, is there an easier solution? Because with mine I was able to group by `a` and `b`. Then with the second line I was able to sum `d` values. I just needed to count distinct `c` values. I was thinking using a HashMap with `c` field as key.

Comment: only easier solution  I can think of doing it using DataFrames. If my answer has solved your question please consider `upvoting` and `accepting` it. @jjrjrjjjr

Comment: But I don't understand why you do getString, I mean I don't know how many rows my csv has. I edit the post, maybe I can give you more details.

Comment: @jjrjrjjjr If its working for you,  if you are okay please care to accept [the answer as owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/369717) and [vote-up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/369717)